# SQL JOIN structure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm working on a SQL query that someone wrote years ago and I'm trying to understand why it takes about 30 seconds to run.

The query has a type of join I've never seen before.

I'm hoping someone can point me to a resource or let me know how this join works.

It's not the join syntax that is confusing me, it's how the join is structured with the INNER JOIN right after the LEFT OUTER JOIN.

Here is the line in question:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JudicialCasePreceptor AS p 
INNER JOIN dbo.Preceptors AS pr 
ON p.UserInfoUID = pr.UID ON e.JudicialCaseUID = p.JudicialCaseUID
```

Here is the whole query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
     e.JudicialCaseUID, e.DistrictUID, e.DistrictName, e.ShortName, 
     e.UserInfoUID, e.UserEmail, e.CustomDiagnosis, e.UserName, 
     e.DateSubmitted, e.DateUpdated, e.CaseItemUID, e.CaseType, 
     e.SettingName, e.Age, e.PL, e.gender, e.Age_gender, 
     e.CaseTypeID, e.Notes, e.EncounterType, e.FTCCourseID, e.PL AS GroupName, 
     a.Name AS AliasName, p.UserInfoUID AS PreceptorUID, 
     pr.FirstName + ' ' + pr.LastName AS PreceptorName, e.PatientType
FROM dbo.view_CaseInfo AS e 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CaseItem AS a 
        ON a.UID = e.CaseItemUID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.JudicialCasePreceptor AS p 
                         INNER JOIN dbo.Preceptors AS pr 
        ON p.UserInfoUID = pr.UID ON e.JudicialCaseUID = p.JudicialCaseUID
```

Thanks!

Comment: Its just [nesting the joins](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5100257/314291). I would focus performance attention on the join conditions (e.g. indexes on the foreign keys). Also, are there no filters? Does the view do some heavy lifting?

Comment: Try to avoid Distinct. And check whether there are indexes based on join columns. If exists, check index fragmentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be clearer if the query was indented appropriately and included the parentheses:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
     e.JudicialCaseUID, e.DistrictUID, e.DistrictName, e.ShortName, 
     e.UserInfoUID, e.UserEmail, e.CustomDiagnosis, e.UserName, 
     e.DateSubmitted, e.DateUpdated, e.CaseItemUID, e.CaseType, 
     e.SettingName, e.Age, e.PL, e.gender, e.Age_gender, 
     e.CaseTypeID, e.Notes, e.EncounterType, e.FTCCourseID, e.PL AS GroupName, 
     a.Name AS AliasName, p.UserInfoUID AS PreceptorUID, 
     pr.FirstName + ' ' + pr.LastName AS PreceptorName, e.PatientType
FROM dbo.view_CaseInfo AS e 
    INNER JOIN dbo.CaseItem AS a 
        ON a.UID = e.CaseItemUID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (dbo.JudicialCasePreceptor AS p 
                      INNER JOIN dbo.Preceptors AS pr 
                            ON p.UserInfoUID = pr.UID)
      ON e.JudicialCaseUID = p.JudicialCaseUID
```

Imagine that the partial resultset inside the parentheses

```
  (dbo.JudicialCasePreceptor AS p 
      INNER JOIN dbo.Preceptors AS pr 
           ON p.UserInfoUID = pr.UID)
```

was created first, and then this intermediate result set is outer joined to the results of the first inner join ...

on another note, be aware that `inner`, `outer`, and `as` are optional, and once you are familiar with this, the sql is shorter and reads easier without them:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
     e.JudicialCaseUID, e.DistrictUID, e.DistrictName, e.ShortName, 
     e.UserInfoUID, e.UserEmail, e.CustomDiagnosis, e.UserName, 
     e.DateSubmitted, e.DateUpdated, e.CaseItemUID, e.CaseType, 
     e.SettingName, e.Age, e.PL, e.gender, e.Age_gender, 
     e.CaseTypeID, e.Notes, e.EncounterType, e.FTCCourseID, e.PL GroupName, 
     a.Name AliasName, p.UserInfoUID PreceptorUID, 
     pr.FirstName + ' ' + pr.LastName PreceptorName, e.PatientType
FROM dbo.view_CaseInfo e 
    JOIN dbo.CaseItem a 
        ON a.UID = e.CaseItemUID
    LEFT JOIN (dbo.JudicialCasePreceptor AS p 
                  JOIN dbo.Preceptors AS pr 
                      ON p.UserInfoUID = pr.UID)
      ON e.JudicialCaseUID = p.JudicialCaseUID
```

Comment: Adding the parentheses does not answer the question.

Comment: In fairness to Charles, OP has 2 questions - clarification of the syntax, and an implied call for performance tuning advice.

Comment: My answer is about the syntax

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is correct.  The `left outer join` is being turned into an inner join by this sequence.  The conditions in the `inner join` include `p`.  So, if there are no matching records in `p`, then `p.UserInfoUid` will be `NULL` and the inner join will fail.

Join's are interpreted in reading order (the order they are written in).  This for interpretation.  The actual execution can be in any order.