# How to optimize SELECT DISTINCT when using multiple Joins?

Tags: t-sql, optimization, distinct

I have read that using cte's you can speed up a select distinct up to 100 times. [Link to the website](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic873124-338-5.aspx#bm1013403) . They have this following example:

```
USE     tempdb;
GO
DROP    TABLE dbo.Test;
GO
CREATE  TABLE 
    dbo.Test 
    (
    data            INTEGER NOT NULL,
    );
GO
CREATE  CLUSTERED INDEX c ON dbo.Test (data);
GO
-- Lots of duplicated values
INSERT  dbo.Test WITH (TABLOCK)
    (data)
SELECT  TOP (5000000)
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) / 117329
FROM    master.sys.columns C1,
    master.sys.columns C2,
    master.sys.columns C3;
 GO

WITH    RecursiveCTE
AS      (
    SELECT  data = MIN(T.data)
    FROM    dbo.Test T
    UNION   ALL
    SELECT  R.data
    FROM    (
            -- A cunning way to use TOP in the recursive part of a CTE :)
            SELECT  T.data,
                    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY T.data)
            FROM    dbo.Test T
            JOIN    RecursiveCTE R
                    ON  R.data < T.data
            ) R
    WHERE   R.rn = 1
    )
SELECT  *
FROM    RecursiveCTE
OPTION  (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

How would one apply this to a query that has multiple joins? For example i am trying to run this query found below, however it takes roughly two and a half minutes. How would I optimize this accordingly?

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.code
From         jpa 
INNER JOIN   jp  ON jpa.ID=jp.ID 
INNER JOIN   jd  ON (jd.ID=jp.ID And jd.JID=3)
INNER JOIN  l ON  jpa.ID=l.ID AND l.CID=3
INNER JOIN   fa  ON fa.ID=jpa.ID
INNER JOIN x ON fa.ID=x.ID
```

Comment: How does a recursive CTE apply to the second?

Comment: Well I was wondering if it could be applied?

Comment: You want to apply recursive CTE where you don't need recursion because it helped in a totally unrelated query?  You ask "how can I apply this"?

Answer (score 1):

1) GROUP BY on every column worked faster for me.

2) If you have duplicates in some of the tables then you can also pre select that and join from that as an inner query.

3) Generally you can nest join if you expect that this join will limit data. 
[SQL join format - nested inner joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099420/sql-join-format-nested-inner-joins)

Comment: I ve tried using Group By but for me it was actually slower

Comment: @AC007: What about the other options?

Comment: I ve only just seen your edits so I will give them a go now and let you know soon , thanks for the input :)

Comment: Since I am only looking for the distinct values x.code as the result of all the joins and the restrictions set in such joins , how would i implement your other two options? Basically I need the distinct list of x.codes based on all the restrictions set out in my inner joins. Having trouble wrapping my head around the other two options.

Comment: How do you know it is due to "distinct"? It looks like you limit it all by id so unique so it should be super fast.

Comment: I think you re right. For some reason after having a look at my execution plans it seems that the biggest problem is one of the joins because its joining to a  900+ million table

Comment: Right. So you might make sure it has indexes on the joined keys and that it is joined using nested join syntax.