# What type of SQL join is it in which the inner-join is not directly followed by an ON clause?

Tags: sql-server, join

What is the name of this type of join? I've looked all over! The query is inner-joining back-to-back and then specifying two ON clauses.

Bonus points: What is the benefit of joining this way?

```
SELECT
    <some columns>
FROM
    ProductTypes AS t0
INNER JOIN Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
        ON t2.CodeId = t1.CodeId
        AND t2.[Enabled] = 1
    ON t1.ClassId = t0.ClassId
```

Comment: INNER JOINS are commutative, but OUTER JOINS are not. This style matters and is often quite useful in assembling OUTER JOINS, and the possibility exists that this join was originally written as an OUTER JOIN before being refactored to an INNER JOIN. When not completely rewriting refactored code I for one like to minimize the change footprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a form of doing nested joins. There's no purpose with all inner unless you want to do it for readability. It can be useful if you use left outer. Consider:

```
SELECT
    <some columns>
FROM
    ProductTypes AS t0
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2
        ON t2.CodeId = t1.CodeId
        AND t2.[Enabled] = 1
    ON t1.ClassId = t0.ClassId
```

Now this does something. If you did it without putting the t1/t0 at the end the t1/t2 inner would basically negate the fact that t1/t0 is a left outer. So doing it this way lets you have t0 records with no t1 records (just like a normal left outer join), but will only show the t1 records that ALSO have a t2. The inner join is enforced at this lower level.

See also:

http://sqlity.net/en/1435/a-join-a-day-nested-joins/

[SQL join format - nested inner joins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099420/sql-join-format-nested-inner-joins)

Answer (score 2):

Still it will be `INNER JOIN`.

It will interpreted as

```
SELECT <some columns> 
FROM   producttypes AS t0 
       INNER JOIN table2 AS t2 
               ON t1.classid = t0.classid 
       INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 
               ON t2.codeid = t1.codeid 
                  AND t2.[enabled] = 1
```

Compiler is smart enough to rearrange the `JOIN` order

Here is demo of what's happening internally. I have used my own table's with similar `JOIN` order

Your query `JOIN` order

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    users AS t0
INNER JOIN products AS t1
    INNER JOIN orders AS t2
        ON t2.productid = t1.productid
        AND t2.productid = 1
    ON t2.uid = t0.uid
```

**Execution Plan**

[image]

The rearranged `JOIN` order

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
    users AS t0
        INNER JOIN orders AS t2
            ON t2.uid = t0.uid 
INNER JOIN products AS t1
        ON t2.productid = t1.productid
        AND t2.productid = 1
```

**Execution Plan**

[image]

As you can see both has identical execution plan. So there wont be any difference

Comment: I like this answer but why write it as I found it?

Comment: @NTDLS - Then who found it?

Comment: I found it in production code but it made no sense to me. Now I know why!